# Rmarkdown - Use table name as variable in dynamic sql chunk?

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown

I need to execute an SQL-engine chunk in my Rmarkdown, where the *table* which is queried has a dynamic name, defined by R code.
I know that linking variables to the current R-environment is doable by using `?`, but this works only for strings and numerics, not for "objects".

Of course I could just run the SQL query with `DBI::dbGetQuery()` but this would imply building all my request (which is very long) as a string which is not comfortable (I have many chunks to run).

Basically what I would need is :

```
`` {r}
mytable <- "name_of_table_on_sql_server"
``
```

then

```
`` {sql} 
select * from ?mytable
``
```

This fails because the created query is `select * from "name_of_table_on_sql_server"` where SQL would need `select * from name_of_table_on_sql_server` (without quotes).

Using `glue` for defining mytable as `mytable <- glue("name_of_table_on_sql_server")` is not working neither.

Any idea ?

Comment: I am not so sure. But maybe , `mytable <- noquote("name_of_table_on_sql_server")`

Comment: No, this gets same error as `glue()` or `as.name()`:

`Error in interpolate_from_env(conn, sql) : 
Object(s) not found: " name_of_table_on_sql_servers "
Failed to execute SQL chunk`

(note the blanks around the table name ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slight variant on what you posted works for me (I don't have SQL Server so I tested with `sqlite`):

```
`` {r}
library(glue)
mytable <- glue_sql("name_of_table_on_sql_server")
``
```

then

```
`` {sql} 
select * from ?mytable;
``
```

My only real changes were to use the function `glue_sql` and add a semicolon (`;`) to the end of the `SQL` chunk.

Comment: Thank you ! 
This solution works perfectly. I would never have had the idea of looking for this `sql_glue` function.